# Is there an algorithm that gives a fixed result and also reversible to find the input from the result?

Tags: algorithm

I'm searching for a function/algorithm like a hash algorithm. It takes an arbitrary number of bytes as input and gives a fixed-sized output. But the main difference is I want it to be reversible.

Comment: Don't you see it's impossible? You can't build a bijective function from an infinite set to a finite set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is impossible because of the [*Pigeonhole Principle*](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle). The Pigeonhole Principle says that if you have n pigeonholes and m pigeons, and m > n, then there will be at least one pigeonhole with at least two pigeons in it.

This Principle has been mathematically proven, there is no way around it. In fact, the proof is simple enough that it can be done by high school students, and often is assigned as homework. You can try it yourself, for example, take two drawers and three socks and try to place the socks in the drawers so that there is only at most one sock in each drawer. You will quickly see that it is impossible.

Therefore, a total function from a domain D to a codomain C, where the cardinality |D| of D is greater than the cardinality |C| of C (i.e. |D| > |C|) can *never* be bijective.

> I'm searching for a function/algorithm like a hash algorithm. It takes an arbitrary number of bytes as input and gives a fixed-sized output.

By the way, that is just the definition of a hash algorithm. So, your "function like a hash algorithm" is just a [hash algorithm](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function).